# Internet Explorer generating new session every time script is requested from another domain

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session

I have a website that is loading a javascript file from another domain. This javascript file is actually a php file which uses sessions, and in browsers other than Internet Explorer the session data is working as expected - on first request the session data is set, then subsequently this session data is available.

However, in IE the session is constantly given a new session id and the data is not retained. I have looked around for solutions, and have tried setting the following header on the remote site without luck:

```
header('P3P: CP="ALL ADM DEV PSAi COM OUR OTRo STP IND ONL"');
```

This was based on information in this SO question [Why is IE7 rejecting session cookies from a page in a frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363199/why-is-ie7-rejecting-session-cookies-from-a-page-in-a-frame) - but in truth, I'm not sure the issue is the same one.

Answer (score 0):

I bet the same thing is happening in Safari too... Internet Explorer won't do that for security reasons, and while that header used to work, I am fairly certain it doesn't anymore.

What you're getting at is that you want the session to persist on the other domain?

You could try using a php wrapper on the local site that calls `file_get_contents()` on the other remote page and then outputs the file as js using `header('Content-type: text/javascript');`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To clarify though, you talk about session persistance on the remote domain - yes, that is correct, but I'm not trying to share session data between the domains (if that is what you mean). Unfortunately, the file_get_contents() approach is not practical, as I need the solution to be javascript only on the originating domain.